# How to get the filename in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

My Spark applications take a folder as the input which contains lots of text file. How can I get filename of each input split programatically?

Answer (score 0):

try this.it worked for me. Hope it will help you.

```
val data = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://master:port/vijay/mywordcount/")

val files = data.map { case (filename, content) => filename}

files.collect.foreach( filename => {
    doSomething(filename) // or print file name

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot retrieve the filename from which input originated.

However if you use Hadoop HDFS FileSystem api you can list the content of the directory. And iterate over all files.
But this is not pure spark program anymore. And it is dependent on the storage layer used (HDFS, amazon s3, etc).